# Never caught this fish before

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

[image]

After catching a bunch of mangrove snapper using live shrimp, my son caught this fish in about a foot of brackish saltwater water off a dock near a rock wall in  Vero Beach at around 10:00 AM  on July 5th. Fish was about 6 inches long and had a wide mouth with  small pointy teeth and what appeared to be two small horns/bumps that protruded from behind its eyes. Never encountered it before.

Comment: Juvenile snakehead?

Comment: Looks like a sculpin (Cottoidea, Cottus). Hard to pin down what kind as there are a bunch, but that very wide head is pretty distinctive.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment into an answer as no one else has jumped in-

This fish closely resembles a sculpin of some kind. This is a very large and diverse family, but many of them share distinctive features. The quite wide head and horns that you describe and show are common in this family. Where I am from (Northwest USA), the Red Irish Lord / cabezon is a gamefish sculpin that can grow to be quite large, and closely resembles this picture of yours (a rather small specimen shown in Figure 1).

[image: https://srelherp.uga.edu/jd/jdweb/fishing/fishll/redirishlord.htm]

Figure 1.

Based on where you are in Vero Beach (Florida?), I have looked a little bit and there is a chance that it is a [Gulf Toadfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_toadfish) (Figure 2) based on its appearance and where you caught it. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvcBs.jpg) is another fisherman's account (with pictures) of a similar fish.

[image: wikipedia image]

Figure 2.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that it is a *Enophrys bison*. Some of the pictures similar to the one you have caught that I found are:
[image]

The presence of the horns is one of the indicators similar in both images(mine and yours). Another similar image is:

[image]

Also about its habitat I found this:
[image]

Might explain why you caught it where you caught it(in a shallow brackish,rocky place). You ought to crosscheck it as I am no expert.

Comment: Could be wrong but this species appears to be specific to the Pacific Ocean according to your species range quote? The OP caught the fish in Florida (Atlantic Ocean).

Comment: Yes I saw that issue and had deleted this post. But then un-deleted in case there is some connection.